# jQuery ajax json -- viewing incorrect data returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, json

I am using the jQuery `$.ajax({dataType: 'json'})` extensively in a client/server environment and it works great...when it works great. The problem is that when the server malfunctions, it does not return the error message (I'm using python with `cgitb`) in json format.  What I would like to do is keep `dataType: 'json'` for the `success:` function, but get raw text or html for the `error:` function -- is there a way to get the unparsed server response from jQuery in either the data or errorThown sections?

Comment: One solution would be to simply remove `dataType: 'json'` and set the right content type response headers. jQuery will still parse the JSON automatically when the right header is set.

Comment: You can also use `complete` handler rather than `success`. Complete receives `( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )`, of which `jqHXR.responseText` should give you the raw response.

Comment: is it possible though that a query could mistakenly be recognized as ``success:`` even if it's returned as non-JSON? I'd hate to have to write checkers for whether the data is returned as JSON or not in each of the ``success: function() `` handlers. But this, or Nikhil's suggestion may be the way to go.

Comment: You should also consdider configuring your server to send back a non-200 response code when there is an error.

Comment: Mike -- in the production environment, definitely; in the test environment, I'm just using Python's CGIHTTPServer, which, unfortunately, sends back a 200 OK immediately upon loading the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that cgitb's `reset()` function, designed to "get out" of a bad HTML situation, was screwing up the jQuery parsing so that by the time jqXHR was passed to `error`, the `responseText` tag was empty.  The error displayed fine on Safari and Chrome, but it was actually extremely badly formed HTML.  I ended up replacing some of the functions in `cgitb` and using the cgitb.handle() function rather than ever calling `cgitb.enable`.  Here is a bit of the code:

```
import sys
import cgitb

def noRest():
    return "Content-Type: text/html\n\n<html>\n"
cgitb.reset = noRest
oldhtml = cgitb.html
def newHTML((etype, evalue, etb), context=5):
    x = oldhtml((etype, evalue, etb), context)
    return x + "\n</body></html>\n"
cgitb.html = newHTML

try:
     [ main script here ]
except Exception as e:
     cgitb.handler(sys.exc_info())
```

Then the `$.ajax({ })` routine could be left alone and `error: function(xhr) { }` worked on `xhr.responseText`.